# Calculating the Fourier Transform of $\sin(\omega_0t)\times\Pi(\frac{t-\frac{T}{2}}{T})$

Tags: solution-verification, fourier-transform, convolution, dirac-delta

So, in order to calculate the Fourier Transform of:
$$x(t) = 
\sin(\omega_0t)\times\Pi(\frac{t-\frac{T}{2}}{T})$$

I've begun by calculating the Fourier Transform of each of the factors.

According to this [Fourier Transform pair table](https://ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/baug/ibk/structural-mechanics-dam/education/identmeth/fourier.pdf):

$$A(\omega) = 
\mathcal{F}\{\sin(\omega_0t)\}=\frac{\pi}{j}[\delta(\omega-\omega_0)-\delta(\omega+\omega_0)] =
-\pi j[\delta(\omega-\omega_0)-\delta(\omega+\omega_0)]$$

And since the second factor can be written as: $$\Pi(\frac{t-\frac{T}{2}}{T})=
\begin{cases}
1,  & 0<t<T \\
0, & otherwise
\end{cases}$$

Its Fourier Transform can be calculated by:

$$B(\omega)=
\mathcal{F}\{\Pi(\frac{t-\frac{T}{2}}{T})\} =
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \Pi(\frac{t-\frac{T}{2}}{T})\times e^{-j\omega t}\, dt =
\int_0^T 1\times e^{-j\omega t}\, dt = 
\dots = 
\frac{1-e^{-j\omega T}}{j\omega}$$

Therefore, since multiplication in the time domain is equal to convolution in the frequency domain:

$$\mathcal{F}\{x(t)\} = 
\mathcal{F}\{\sin(\omega_0t)\times\Pi(\frac{t-\frac{T}{2}}{T})\} = 
A(\omega)*B(\omega) = 
\{-\pi j[\delta(\omega-\omega_0)-\delta(\omega+\omega_0)]\}*\{\frac{1-e^{-j\omega T}}{j\omega}\}
$$

Now, after using the linearity property and the sifting property of the delta function:

$$\mathcal{F}\{x(t)\} = -\pi j \{\delta(\omega-\omega_0)*\frac{1-e^{-j\omega T}}{j\omega}-\delta(\omega+\omega_0)*\frac{1-e^{-j\omega T}}{j\omega}\} = 
\dots = 
\pi \{\frac{1-e^{j(\omega+\omega_0)T}}{\omega+\omega_0}-\frac{1-e^{j(\omega-\omega_0)T}}{\omega-\omega_0}\}$$

Is my solution correct?